# Audio driver should be present in Linux kernel but device isn't recognised

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, pulseaudio

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 on my Asus E200H laptop. Based on what I've seen the audio device for this laptop should be supported in the mainline kernel that Ubuntu 19.10 uses. I'm getting no audio output, and in Ubuntu Sound Settings the output device is listed as Dummy Output, which would indicate that the device was not recognised. Is there something I can do to prompt Ubuntu to recognise the device?

For reference, this is the output of 'uname -a'...

```
Linux zenoarrow-E200HA 5.3.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 09:22:33 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the relevant section of the 5.3 kernel changelog that shows that support for the required codec (Conexant CX2072X) was added...

https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxChanges#Linux_5.3.Audio

In one of the two relevant kernel commits, the developer lists testing on a Asus E200HA, which should be very similar/the same as my laptop (I don't know what the differences between the E200H and E200HA are, but I doubt these differences are audio related as I've used "E200HA" audio patches in the past)...

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=3917da94f787e6c907e440653ead0c666a71379e

> Tested with ASUS E200HA laptop.

Before these patches landed in the mainline kernel I built a custom 4.19 kernel with patches to support the audio hardware in my laptop, and this worked out fine. I'll be going back to using this kernel for now, but I would appreciate any support I can get Ubuntu to work with the audio hardware after a standard install.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I will report a bug as requested, but I'm also leaving this question unanswered for now as I would also like to know if there is a way to force Ubuntu to recognise the devices (perhaps using tools available in the terminal or through config file changes), and if this is possible it may also be useful to other Ubuntu users in the future.

Comment: Report a bug yo launchpad. Maybe this device is not enabled in kernel config.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: If the device is not recognized by kernel, it isn't possible to enable it. Also it will be useful if you add output of `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3`. Anyway it is a kernel bug.

Comment: You can recompile Ubuntu kernel and enable the module in config.

Comment: "You can recompile Ubuntu kernel and enable the module in config." Yes, I'm aware of that. As stated before... "Before these patches landed in the mainline kernel I built a custom 4.19 kernel with patches to support the audio hardware in my laptop, and this worked out fine."

Comment: This patch has been applied to Ubuntu kernel as I see in git. Most likely they forgot to enable building of the new module in kernel config.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6. Just FYI I've updated the following bug in Launchpad... https://bugs.launchpad.net/alsa-driver/+bug/1563110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why this question was downvoted. In any case, I was able to get a fix for this issue, turns out that I needed a newer version of alsa-lib (1.2.1.1-1) in order to get the required files to fix the audio. Should just need to download this package and run update-initramfs in order to get the audio device recognised. Will mark this question as answered.